# Goutte/Guzzle Set Configuration Option

Tags: symfony, curl, web-scraping, guzzle, goutte

I'm crawling a web page that's returning a redirect, so I'd like to add a configuration option into my `crawler` that that will let me set `allow_redirects` to `false`. Looking at the guzzle.readthedocs.org web page in regards to redirects, it says

```
$response = $client->get('http://github.com', ['allow_redirects' => false]);
echo $response->getStatusCode();
// 301
```

Since I am using Goutte with Symfony2, these commands are a little different. For example:

```
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Can anyone help me discover how I can add the guzzle `allow_redirects` to the configuration? I feel that this will help me to not get page content that I want and not a `crawler` full of redirect code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is, how to "translate" `['allow_redirects' => false]` into Goutte-syntax?

Well, here's how to set up cURL options in Goutte: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte (search for "Fine-tune cURL options:")

And http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php gives you the name of the option you're looking for: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

So putting it all together:

```
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false;
```

If that's not what you asked for, please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: When I try this I get the following error "Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given". The code I am using is: $this->client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);